# Desaturated Animation After Rendering

Tags: rendering, color-management

Working on this animation and the colors look correct in the 3d viewport:

[image: correct]

but when I render the PNGs:

[image: PNG]

and then render to AVI RAW:

[image]

in the VSE it becomes super desaturated.  I have the "Display Device" at sRGB, "View Transform" is standard, "Look" is none, and "Sequencer" is sRGB.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

[Blend file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QMr1X2cf_HuP2ePbXeC3fzmCu_RkUpcS/view?usp=sharing) (2.80).

Thanks!

Comment: Any progress on this? It would be good to know for certain how the output is being busted up.

Answer (score 1):

You are on a Mac right?

I’m guessing it is post 2015 MacBook Pro?

Blender doesn’t support the proper display devices for MacBook Pros. You’ll need my GitHub version.

TL;DR: What you are seeing in Blender is wrong, and Preview is interpreting it as correct. I’d also encourage you to not render with the sRGB OETF as it is subject to colour skew with saturated colours.

PS: If this confuses you, I’ve recently covered this very subject over at the Hitchhiker’s Guide to Digital Colour. I’d recommend starting at the first question if this guess of an answer proved correct. https://hg2dc.com/. Feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what I configured that made my image sequence render perfectly fine without weirdly desaturating or altering the contrast.

Display Device: sRGB
View Transform: sRGB OETF
Look: None
Squencer: sRGB OETF